# AngularJS ng-controller statement

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following markup...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>priklad00007</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="priklad00007.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyFirstCtrl">
        <h2>Number of employees: {{ourEmployees.length}}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

With the following JavaScript...

```
function MyFirstCtrl($scope) {
    var employees = ["Karel Novak", "Martin Cervenka", "Jana Zelena", "Frantisek Vomacka"];
    $scope.ourEmployees = employees;
}
```

I expect to get

> Number of employees: 4

But I am instead getting

> Number of employees: {{ourEmployees.length}}

What could be going wrong?

Comment: you must add your function MyFirstCtrl to your angular.module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are declaring controllers seems to be off. Try the following, where in this case, `'app'` is your AngularJS app name...

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyFirstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var employees = ["Karel Novak", "Martin Cervenka", "Jana Zelena", "Frantisek Vomacka"];
    $scope.ourEmployees = employees;    
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jg198gwo/) - working example

---

See the docs for more information - [Understanding Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)